# Bazel build: dependency parameterized by command line

Tags: c++, c, build, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a project for a plugin in C/C++ where I have different implementations and I would like to be able to select which implementation to use when building.

```
WORKSPACE
plugin/
    BUILD
    plugin.c
    plugin.h
plugin_impl1/
    BUILD
    ...
plugin_impl2/
    BUILD
    ...
```

*plugin_impl1/BUILD:*

```
cc_library(
  name = "plugin_impl1"
  srcs = [...]
  hdrs = [...]
)
```

*plugin_impl2/BUILD:*

```
cc_library(
  name = "plugin_impl2"
  srcs = [...]
  hdrs = [...]
)
```

I want to know how to write *plugin/BUILD* so that I could write something like:

```
bazel build //plugin --which plugin_impl2
```

The executable name should always be the same so **having multiple rules with different target names (for plugin) is not an option.**